# How to transform an Array[List[Int]] into RDD[(int,int,int)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

The following function needs to return an `RDD[(int,int,int)]`:

```
def getResults(sc:SparkContext, lower_bound:Int, upper_bound:Int, data_path:String):RDD[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    ...
    val result = mapping.map(x=>x._2).map(x=>x.head.toArray)
}
```

However, I get the following result instead:

> scala> result.collect res117: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(10398, 55,
>   120), Array(10286, 35, 100))

How can I return the result as an `RDD[(int,int,int)]` back to `Main`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply `collect` (or `map` if you can guarantee the shape) with [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html):

```
result.collect { case Array(x, y, z) => (x, y, z) }
```